# Handle Time.timeScale onChange event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm started with Unity, and I need (before game is in paused) trigger an avent. Is there any way to trigger any event when the `Time.timeScale` is changed to 0? Something like: `Time.timeScale.onBeforeChange()`...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried put it in void Update() ?

Comment: Honestly, I dislike using `Time.timeScale` for pausing, I'd much rather have a boolean in my main game class that, if true, skips all game logic during `Update()`, which allows me to still have a meaningful deltaTime value for doing things like tweening menus and so on.

Comment: Thanks, draco18s, but i need to hande also if user close application unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the thing that changes the time scale a controller, then make that controller raise the event.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BeforeTimeChangedData
{
    public bool canceled;
    public float oldValue;
    public float newValue;
}


[System.Serializable]
public class BeforeTimeChangedEvent : UnityEvent<BeforeTimeChangedData>
{
}

//Attach this to a game object that gets loaded in your pre-load scene with the tag "Singletons"
public class TimeController : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        if(BeforeTimeChanged == null)
            BeforeTimeChanged = new BeforeTimeChangedEvent();
    }

    public BeforeTimeChangedEvent BeforeTimeChanged;

    public bool ChangeTimeScale(float newValue)
    {
        var args = new BeforeTimeChangedData();
        args.oldValue = Time.timeScale;
        args.newValue = Time.timeScale;
        BeforeTimeChanged.Invoke(args);
        if(!args.canceled)
        {
            Time.timeScale = newValue;
        }
        return args.canceled;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere you can change the timescale by doing

```
public class TimeSlower : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private TimeController _timeController;
    public Text TimeChanged;

    void Start()
    {
        var singletons = GameObject.FindWithTag("Singletons");
        _timeController = singletons.GetComponent<TimeController>();
        if(_timeController == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Could not find a TimeController on the Singletons object");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("SlowTime"))
        {
            var changed = _timeController.ChangeTimeScale(0.5f);
            if(changed)
            {
                TimeChanged.text = "Time Changed!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is another component that listens for the change and cancels the change if the change has happened too recently;

```
public class TimeChangeLimiter : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float lastTimeChange = 0;
    private TimeController _timeController;
    public Text TimeChanged;

    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
    public float Cooldown;

    void Start()
    {
        var singletons = GameObject.FindWithTag("Singletons");
        _timeController = singletons.GetComponent<TimeController>();
        if(_timeController == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Could not find a TimeController on the Singletons object");

        _timeController.BeforeTimeChanged.AddListener(OnBeforeTimeChanged);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        _timeController.BeforeTimeChanged.RemoveListener(OnBeforeTimeChanged);
    }


    void OnBeforeTimeChanged(BeforeTimeChangedData args)
    {
        if(Time.time - lastTimeChange < Cooldown)
        {
            args.canceled = true;
            return;
        }
        lastTimeChange = Time.time;
    }
}
```